# Rails paperclip - Adding dynamic multiple images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

I'm trying to add a dynamic number of pictures to an element called "component".
Looking around I've created this code:

component.rb

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :component_id, :photo_file_size

    belongs_to :component, :foreign_key => :component_id
    has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {
         :thumb => "75x75>",
         :small => "200x200>"
    }
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for setup_component(@component) , :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
...
  <h2> PHOTOS </h2>
<% f.fields_for @component.images.build do |p| %>
        <h2>Photo</h2>
          <p><%= f.label :data %><br /><%= f.file_field :data %></p>
<% end %>
```

application_helper.rb

```
def setup_component(comp)

    return comp.images.build if comp.images.empty?
end
```

So I'm getting the following error when I try going to form:

```
undefined method `images_path'
```

Comment: Where does `images_path` appear in your code?

Comment: Id doesn't appear. But the problem disappear when I comment this line:
`return comp.images.build if comp.images.empty?`.
Now I'm doing this in controller and it works, but when I submit the form, it crashes. So something more is wrong.

Comment: usually, `fields_for` uses to the association : `fields_for @component.images`. Does this help ?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting your `images_path` error because you're not setting your form up right

**Why is this code not in your controller?**

```
def setup_component(comp)
    return comp.images.build if comp.images.empty?
end
```

Your form_for object needs to have a clear variable definition, to allow an ActiveRecord object to be created. Rails takes the variable you assign to the `form_for`, and uses it to build an entire structure for the form, and a return path (in case of errors). Currently, your form builds a new image, which is why it's returning the images_path error.

```
<%= form_for setup_component(@component)
```

You'd be better writing this:

```
#app/controllers/component_controller.rb
def new_image
    @comp = Comp.new
    @comp.images.build
end
```

Then your form can be called from your /new/ route, thus giving rails a real route to bring you back to.

---

Secondly, your form has this:

```
<% f.fields_for @component.images.build do |p| %>
        <h2>Photo</h2>
          <p><%= f.label :data %><br /><%= f.file_field :data %></p>
<% end %>
```

This should change to:

```
<%= f.fields_for :images do |p| %>
        <h2>Photo</h2>
          <p><%= p.label :data %><br /><%= p.file_field :data %></p>
<% end %>
```